# VPN detects that connection is from another country using another VPN

Tags: window, vpn

The problem is that I use VPN in the country X and when I use it in the country Y, it doesn't work.
I've tried to connect that VPN with IP address from the country X with another VPN, but again doesn't work.
This is because of wifi network or another configuration in my laptop?
Is is possible modify something and to connect that VPN?

It will be interesting to know how it works and why it happens.
Thank you all in advance.